# Can we change dynamically the interval of "schedule"?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a game on iPhone using cocos2d, and I have a question.
In my init method I'm doing this :

```
[self schedule:@selector(newMonster:) interval:1];
```

It create a new monster every second.
But I'd like that the interval change over time. For example :

- The 10 first seconds of the game: a new monster appears every 1 second.
- Then for 10 seconds: a new monster appears every 0.8 second.
- And after every 0.5 second...

How can I do that?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this- (I have copied some code from @bddckr)

Initial time:

```
self.monsterSpawnStartDate = [NSDate date];
self.lastTimeScheduledBefore = 0;//new var
```

Scheduled Method to create monster

```
- (void)scheduledMethod {
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:monsterSpawnStartDate];

    [self newMonster]; // Let a new monster spawn
    if (seconds >= 20.0  && lastTimeScheduledBefore == 10){
      [self unschedule:@(scheduledMethod)];
      [self unschedule:@(scheduledMethod) interval:0.5];
      lastTimeScheduledBefore = 20;
    }
    else if (seconds >= 10.0 && lastTimeScheduledBefore == 0){
      [self unschedule:@(scheduledMethod)];
      [self unschedule:@(scheduledMethod) interval:0.8]
      lastTimeScheduledBefore = 10;
    }
}
```

You can modify it as your need. You can use `mod` if it goes through a cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Make an instance variable and property of `NSDate` called `monsterSpawnStartDate`, make it an retaining property and synthesize it.
As soon as your first monster should be created, set it:

```
self.monsterSpawnStartDate = [NSDate date]; // Current date and time
```

And replace your code by this:

```
[self schedule:@selector(adjustMonsterSpawnRate) interval:0.1]; // Seems like you want it to fire every 0.1 seconds
```

Implement `adjustMonsterSpawnRate` like this:

```
- (void)adjustMonsterSpawnRate {
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:monsterSpawnStartDate];
    if (((seconds <= 10.0) && (seconds % 1.0)) || ((seconds <= 20.0) && (seconds % 0.8)) ((seconds > 20.0) && (seconds % 0.5)))
        [self newMonster]; // Let a new monster spawn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better option would be to use a scheduled function for timing and use accumulated time to trigger the enemy creation as follows

self.time_since_last_monster = 0
[self schedule:@selector(new_monster:) interval:0.3];

```
-(void) new_monster:(ccTime)dt{
     self.time_since_last_monster += dt;
     if(self.time_since_last_monster > monster_interval){
          self.time_since_last_monster -= monster_interval;
          [self create_new_monster];
          // at this point based on some condition, you can now change monster_interval
     }
}
```

This would give more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty dumb, so here's what I'd do:

in the .h set a float

```
float nextMonsterIn;
```

then in the body

```
nextMonsterIn = 1.0;
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(newMonster:) interval:nextMonsterIn];
[self schedule:@selector(kickUpDifficulty:) interval:10];

- (void) newMonster : (ccTime) dt
{
    [self scheduleOnce:@selector(newMonster:) interval:nextMonsterIn];
    //-----make a monster-----
}

- (void) kickUpDifficulty : (ccTime) dt
{
      if(nextMonsterIn == 1.0)
           nextMonsterIn = 0.8;
      else if(nextMonsterIn == 0.8)
      {
           nextMonsterIn = 0.5;
           [self unschedule:@selector(kickUpDifficulty:)];
      }
}
```

Basically every time I call newMonster i'd recursively re-schedule the newMonster based on my current delay, then I can adjust the delay in a timer or every time a monster is killed or wherever.